# Visual Studio 2005 - Add webreference fails for secured webservice

Tags: asp.net, web-services, forms-authentication

I have a webservice (asmx file) in a directory requiring  form authentication

When I try to add the WebReference through VS2005 - I get the following error:

```
The request failed with the error message:
--
<html><head><title>Object moved</title></head><body>
<h2>Object moved to <a href="/webchat/login.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2fwebchat%WebService.asmx">here</a>.</h2>
</body></html>
```

When I remove the web.config in that directory (and basically removing the requirement for form authentication) everything works fine. I can add the WebReference.

Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Place the following code in your web.config:

```
<location path="path/to/your/service.asmx">
    <system.web>
        <authorization>
            <allow users="*"/>
        </authorization>
    </system.web>
</location>
```

ASP.Net allows to override application-wide settings for specific locations.

Comment: Thanks it works. But is there a way I can use it as a webreference while still keeping the authorization requirement?

Comment: AFAIK, its not possible to use the same forms authentication for web services. You should protect your web services using other type of authentication. Take a look at this article: http://www.code-magazine.com/articleprint.aspx?quickid=0307071&printmode=true